# Problems with fprintf while writing large info

Tags: c, arrays, file, fann

I'm trying to write an array of 18000 items (that array is from the transformation wav>array), and when I write the items in a file appears a `\n` when I don't want to write that, here is the code:

```
f = info.frames;
sr = info.samplerate;
c = info.channels;
num_items = f*c;
int arrayPrueba [num_items];

/* Allocate space for the data to be read, then read it. */
buf = (int *) malloc(num_items*sizeof(int));
num = sf_read_int(sf,buf,num_items);
sf_close(sf);
printf("Read %d items\n",num);

/* Write the data to filedata.out. */
out = fopen("filedata.data","a+");
fprintf(out,"13 18000 1\n");
int cont =0;

for (i = 0; i < num; i += c)
{
   for (j = 0; j < c; ++j)
        fprintf(out,"%d ",buf[i+j]);}
}
fprintf(out,"\n%d\n",pasos);
fclose(out);
```

Here is a part of `filedata.data` where appears that jump of line

```
    104333312 103415808 104202240 105250816 104595456 104202240 103022592 103415808 102367232 102236160 104202240 104071168 104464384 103677952 103284736 103809024 102760448 103415808 105644032 102629376 102629376 103940096 103022592 103284736 102891520 104726528 103677952 103284736 102891520 104071168 104202240 102498304 102760448 102367232 100007936 102498304 104071168 104202240 103153664 103940096 103153664 103022592 103284736 103940096 103677952 103546880 102629376 103546880 101974016 102498304 104071168 103546880 103677952 103940096 103284736 102105088 105119744 104071168 103677952 103415808 104071168 104726528 103546880
 103415808 103677952 103940096 105512960 104857600 103940096 103809024 102760448 103022592 103284736 103022592 103153664 104333312 102891520 103940096 104464384 103677952 103940096 102105088 103022592 102629376 104595456 103940096 102236160 102760448 102629376 103940096 102236160 104726528 102760448 102629376 102760448
```

It jumps between 103546880 and 103415808.

I need it without `\n` breakup's because the file.data for FANN training and it can't have jumps.

Comment: Why `"a+"` mode for `fopen` ? I would make it `"w"`....

Comment: How do you know there's an extra newline?

Comment: are you sure thats  extra new line character and editer which you are using to show file is not making any problem in viewing them?

Comment: You might test the result of [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html). It returns a negative value on error.

Comment: check the number of lines in the file with `wc -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot imagine the C library adding an unwanted newline. *Normal* OS and filesystems (Windows and other Unix-like) should not either. Unless you are using a really uncommon operating system or file system -if yes your really should add it in your question-, I presume the unwanted newline was added by the editor when you opened the file to read it by the editor.

To confirm, use the excellent [vim](http://www.vim.org) which is disponible for many platforms. It can read almost everything, even files containing null characters and can convert to hexa to make sure what really is in a file.

I've just created a file with 32000 elements of 10 characters each ('104333312 ') and vim says the line has 320000 characters without trying to split it (of course the line is folded, but correctly counted as only one line).

Answer (score 0):

the problem must be coming from:

```
info.samplerate;
```

Wherever that data is gathered from, something may be causing the embedded newline. Perhaps some quirk in the sampling or perhaps it overruns a buffer prompting a new buffer/line of data to be written. How many data entries do you get before the newline?

Comment: apparantly OP is concerned about extra newline after `fprintf(out,"%d ",buf[i+j]);`

Comment: It is hard to imagine that the newline could resist to the transformation in **`int`** and be written with a **`"%d"`** format !

Answer (score -2):

Replace the line **out = fopen("filedata.data","a+");** with below line.
eg
out = fopen("filedata.data","a+b");

So the file will not have new line character(\n).

Comment: opening the file as binary will not have any effect on `fprintf(out,"%d ",buf[i+j]);`